# How to display table correctly?

Tags: java, html, jstl

I have some data and I want to display it. `telnumbers` and ´teltype` must be in one column at their owner.

I have this:

[image]

and this my code:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<div xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"
     xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
     xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/tags"
     version="2.0">
    <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
    <jsp:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <style>
        table, th, td {
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
    </style>

    <h1>Contact list</h1>

    <c:if test="${not empty contacts}">
        <table>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Birth Date</th>
                <th>tel_type</th>
                <th>tel_number</th>
                <th>hobby</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <c:forEach items="${contacts}" var="contact">
                <jsp:useBean id="contact" scope="page" type="org.training.support.model.Contact"/>
                <tr>
                <td>"${contact.firstName}"</td>
                <td>"${contact.lastName}"</td>
                <td>"${contact.birthDate}"</td>
                    <c:forEach items="${contact.contactDetails}" var="telDetail">
                        <jsp:useBean id="telDetail" scope="page" type="org.training.support.model.ContactTelDetail"/>
                            <td>"${telDetail.telNumber}"</td>
                            <td>"${telDetail.telType}"</td>
                    </c:forEach>
                    <c:forEach items="${contact.hobbies}" var="hobby">
                        <jsp:useBean id="hobby" scope="page" type="org.training.support.model.Hobby"/>
                            <td>"${hobby.id}"</td>
                    </c:forEach>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </c:if>
</div>
```

Comment: Please do not use td for each data. Use some delimiter instead using 2 td

Comment: I think this will helps you. Check the "Cell that spans two column". https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_table_span. If not helping please ask again

Comment: sorry, but i don't know, how i can made random colspan i my example( this good example, but in my case it don't work, cause contact.contactDetails.size() not defined(random)(

Comment: oh my god) i forgot about </br>)) however, thank Varman)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here i have added the code which related to your solution. Kindly add the following tag into your JSP.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
```

And here is the changes

```
<h1>Contact list</h1>

<c:if test="${not empty contacts}">
    <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Birth Date</th>
            <th colspan="${fn:length(contact.contactDetails)}">tel_type & tel_number</th>
            <th colspan="${fn:length(contact.hobbies)}">hobby</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <c:forEach items="${contacts}" var="contact">
            <jsp:useBean id="contact" scope="page" type="org.training.support.model.Contact"/>
            <tr>
            <td>"${contact.firstName}"</td>
            <td>"${contact.lastName}"</td>
            <td>"${contact.birthDate}"</td>
                <c:forEach items="${contact.contactDetails}" var="telDetail">
                    <jsp:useBean id="telDetail" scope="page" type="org.training.support.model.ContactTelDetail"/>
                        <td>"${telDetail.telType}" - "${telDetail.telNumber}"</td>                         
                </c:forEach>
                <c:forEach items="${contact.hobbies}" var="hobby">
                    <jsp:useBean id="hobby" scope="page" type="org.training.support.model.Hobby"/>
                        <td>"${hobby.id}"</td>
                </c:forEach>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</c:if>
```

And the result will be following image

[image: Example result]

Comment: Oh, this more better. I was looking for some like this

Answer (score 0):

For a table to display properly the number of 'th' have to match the number of 'td' within the 'tr' like:

```
<table>
   <thead>
     <tr>
        <th>"Header 1"</th>
        <th>"Header 2"</th>
        <th>"Header 3"</th>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     <tr>
       <td> "Value1"</td>
       <td> "Value2"</td>
       <td> "Value3"</td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
```

In your case without having acces to your tables is hard to tell but since you are using:

`<c:forEach items="${contact.contactDetails}" var="telDetail">`

is giving you more td than 6 as in your # of headers maybe due to the values in your table, check if you have empty or null values. Try to eliminate null values and leaving single space " " on those fields and try again or replace the multiple foreach by a single for loop and address every array by its index.

For example:

```
<c:if test="${not empty contacts}">
    <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Birth Date</th>
            <th>tel_type</th>
            <th>tel_number</th>
            <th>hobby</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <c:forEach begin="0" end="${fn:length(contacts)}" var="i">
            <jsp:useBean id="contact" scope="page" type="org.training.support.model.Contact"/>
            <tr>
                <td>"${contacts[i].firstName}"</td>
                <td>"${contacts[i].lastName}"</td>
                <td>"${contacts[i].birthDate}"</td>
                <td>"${contact.contactDetails[i].telNumber}"</td>
                <td>"${contact.contactDetails[i].telType}"</td>
                <td>"${contact.hobbies[i].id}"</td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</c:if>
```

Make sure you added the this taglib at the top of your page to allow the fn for the size

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
```

Comment: can you help me realize what you meant? i try to do some various examples, but unsuccessfully(

Comment: I added an example of what i was proposing, how ever i can't test it as I don't have your collections or tables but let me know. if somebody spot an error let me know, I'm just trying to help